# bootstrap popover have to be refreshed

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover, document-ready

I use the popover from Bootstrap in my project. For some reasons, I cannot initiallize it in $(document).ready function. I have to use $(window).load like

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.popoverMessage').popover({
        placement: 'right',
        trigger: 'hover focus'
    });
});
```

But if I initiallize the popover like this, I have to refresh the page to get the popover work.
Any idea about this issue? Why do I have to reload page?

---

In the $(document).ready function, I return the popover hyperlink:

```
'<a href="#" class="popoverMessage" title="" data-content="'+users+'">'+data.length+' users</a>'
```

Users and data is from the database.

Comment: Can you post the HTML as well?

Comment: @RayHenry I return the HTML in document.ready

Comment: What do you mean you return the popover hyperlink? Are you saying that you are injecting the anchor tag into the HTML in javaScript?

Comment: @RayHenry It means I just return the popover as a hyperlink tag <a>

Comment: This is too hard to diagnose without seeing your HTML file.